# Datepicker for single page architecuture using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker, single-page-application

How would I add a date picker to single page architecture using angular JS version 1.3.15??

Comment: take a look at angular own datepicker.just by mention `type="date"` for input field http://plnkr.co/edit/ptDGqdcY8cITTL9UU8pq?p=preview otherwise go for angular ui bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Minor grammar edits. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive and apply the datepicker function to the element on the link function.

```
angularModule.directive('datepickerDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
       var datepicker = $(element).datepicker()
       scope.$on('$destroy', fucntion () {
         // destroy datepicker
       });
    }
  };
});
```

You cacn configure as you desire to use it look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
<input type="text" data-datepicker-directive />
```

This is the simpler example, then you should add your logic or use one from the existing libraries (angular-ui, ... etc)

Comment: How to call this function in MVC view?

Comment: I edited the response so it has an usage example, data- is not needed but is a good practice since some versions of ie need it.

Comment: Did you add the datepicker to the page? There is any error on the console?

Comment: there is no error on the console. I added that to view.